# Node fs.js rodando no HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, eu preciso usar a função fs do node.js mas estou encontrando erros. Quando executo usando node use_fs.js ele roda e funciona perfeitamente. Entretanto quando ponho dentro do html ele sempre diz q require is not defined. Ou seja, quando rodo na console funciona e quando ponho no browser não funciona, sei que o fs é uma função core do node.js, mas quando

```js
<script language="javascript">
          var fs = require('fs');
          var fileContent = "Hello World!";
          var filepath = '_folder/file.txt';
          fs.writeFile(filepath, fileContent, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Saved!');
          });
    </script>
```

alguem pode dar uma dica?

Comment: Em que contexto vc esta executando? O browser para acessar o sistema de arquivos do usuário? não ira funcionar a menos que seja um app hibrido com NWJS ou Eletron em um siite não rola não mano

Comment: Na verdade, eu quero obter o hash sha256 de um arquivo e ja tenho a parte de criptografia, mas quando testo no browser para acessar o arquivo, sempre recebo o erro de require is not defined.

Comment: O usuário (no navegador) não pode acessar um arquivo no servidor a menos que, você (no servidor) disponibilize este arquivo... se for **"expressjs"** seria algo como `express.static()` na rota para o arquivo (ou em uma pasta publica). Mesmo que você esteja usando **"Browserify"** o front-end não pode fazer leitura do sistema de arquivos do back-end desta forma... é necessário usar `XMLHttpRequest()` ou `fetch()` de outro jeito não dá não.

Comment: Olá, desculpa, acho q não me fiz entender. O usuário(no navegador) precisa acessar um arquivo local(no pc do usuario). Mas como estou testando ainda e está tudo intranet nao estou conseguindo carregar.

Comment: Mesmo estando em `localhost` não funciona assim, se não for um app hibrido o navegador não pode acessar o sistema de arquivos do usuário programaticamente. Será necessário usar um `<input type="file">` e a api [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File) para ler o arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Há uma diferença em executar o javascript no NodeJs e no Browser, no Node a plataforma mapeia as libs do sistema operacional já no Browser mapeia as do próprio Browser, então não será possível utilizar o fs já que é uma função mapiada para o sistema operacional.